# Unable to connect to remote sql server using nifi

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

I have NiFi running on HDFnode-2 and sl running on HDPnode-1.
Using ExecuteSQl processor I am trying to fetch some data but getting below error:

> ExecuteSQL[id=e50be381-0160-1000-0000-00006ee4f593] Unable to execute
>   SQL select query select * from READ_ACCESS_LOG LIMIT 10; due to
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user
>   'piyushm'@'hdfnode-2.novalocal' (using password: YES)). No FlowFile to
>   route to failure: {}
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user
>   'piyushm'@'hdfnode-2.novalocal' (using password: YES))
>           at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:27

I have provided all the correct values in DPCPool connection configs, still not able to understand why its hitting the nifi node for mysql database.

Comment: The main thing: `Access denied for user 'piyushm'@'hdfnode-2.novalocal'`. Could you provide a full stack trace of this error from nifi-app.log file?

Comment: @daggett Can I shae you the file on ur ID ? Its too long

Comment: And "piyushm" is the username I have provided in CONFIGURE CONTROLLER SERVICE as DatabaseUser.

Note: This MySQL is on HDPnode and dont know why it's making a reference to HDFnode for accessing tables.

Comment: Hi.. I have extracted logs from nifi-app.log file and pasted to 

https://pastebin.com/wJ7EFBpK

If any other logs are to be checked, Plz let me know..!

Comment: definitely the error from your mysql driver : `Access denied for user 'piyushm'@'hdfnode-2.example' (using password: YES)`. if you are saying that there is a wrong node in error, then problem in `url` dbcp parameter.

Comment: jdbc:mysql://hdpnode-3.example:3306/log_data

Here I have put correct HDP node where mysql is installed and log_data is the DB name.  Still its making reference to HDF node where my nifi is installed.

Comment: It seems like there was a host to host permission issue.. Granting the permission did the job right..!

Thanks for looking into it.